# uniform converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

Question: Considering the uniform convergence of series function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{inx}}
{n^{\alpha}}$, with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\in[a,b]\subset (0,2\pi)$.
Series function converges on $[a,b]$.
With $\alpha>1$, I solved and Series function is uniform converging.
With $\alpha\le1$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{inx}}{n^{\alpha}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{cos(nx)}{n^\alpha}+i.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$.
So, why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{cos(nx)}{n^\alpha}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$ uniform converge? How can I prove this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of Fourier series?

Comment: Apply summation by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can prove this when $\alpha>0$.

$\forall0<\delta<\pi$,when $x\in[\delta,2\pi-\delta]$,we have

$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos{kx}|=\left| \frac{\sin{(n+\frac{1}{2})x}-\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}{2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}} \right|\leq \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{\delta}{2}}}$,bounded uniformly.
and $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ is decreasing.According to the Dirichlet test,it converges uniformly.

Comment: With $\alpha<0$, do you have idea?

Comment: @QuangNguyen  When $\alpha \le 0,$ the terms of the series do not converge to $0.$